# File Copy if exists with a slight twist

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, xcopy

I have a source folder `FolderSource` with 200K files that were created in the last 6 months.  New files (about 10k to 11k) are added every day to this folder.

I need to copy them to `FolderDestination` if a file created in the last 30 days does not exist in `FolderArchiveA`, `FolderArchiveB`, `FolderArchiveC`

Here's my algorithm for this

```
1. Get one Filename from SourceFolder where CreatedDate > CurrentDate - 30
2. If Filename Exists in FolderArchiveA go to step 6
3. If Filename Exists in FolderArchiveB go to step 6
4. If Filename Exists in FolderArchiveC go to step 6
5. Copy File defined in FileName to FolderDestination
6. If there are more files to be processed, go to Step 1
```

I wrote this in C#, but I'm going FBAF (think RBAR, but with files).  It takes well over 40 min to execute.

Is there another way I can code this more efficiently using Powershell or XCopy?

Comment: Easily.  Look up `Get-ChildItem` and `Where-Object`.  It utilizes the `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` .NET classes.

Comment: have you checked what part of the process is bottle-necking specifically? you may just be limited by disk i/o.

Comment: @RajMore, if that is a long running service, i'd load all file names into memory, added a File System Watcher to maintain that (as well as a periodic catch all parser) and lookup in that.

Comment: What if the file already exists in `FolderDestination`?

Comment: If file already exists, overwrite

Answer (score 2):

Quick throw-together in PowerShell:

```
#Requires -Version 3

$FolderSource = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Source' -File |
    Where-Object { $PSItem.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }
$FolderDestination = 'C:\Destination'
$Archives = @((Get-ChildItem -Path @('C:\ArchiveA','C:\ArchiveB','C:\ArchiveC') -File |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name').ToUpper() |
    Sort-Object |
    Get-Unique)

ForEach ($File in $FolderSource)
{
    If ($File.Name -notin $Archives)
    {
        $File | Move-Item -Destination $FolderDestination
    }
}
```

There are likely *faster* ways, but this way will *work*.